# How should VBA.CVErr() be used if it cannot support the Long vartype of vbObjectError..?

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I'm in Access 2007 VBA, trying to return an #ERROR value from a function, as shown in the code below. But I've just discovered the largest number which VBA.CVErr(*expression*) will accept is 2^15-1, aka an Integer vartype; not a Long.

This seems incomprehensible, since the VBA constant vbObjectError is a Long. Other error functions work with longs; for instance: `VBA.Error(vbObjectError)` works fine.

In light of this issue, what suggestions are there to properly make use of vbObjectError to return user-defined errors as error objects from user-defined functions..?

```
Public Sub TesUDE()
    Dim v As Variant
    v = UDE()
    Debug.Print TypeName(v), VBA.CStr(v)
End Sub

Public Function UDE() As Variant
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    err.Raise 2 ^ 15 - 1   , , "This is a user-defined error." 'Works.
    err.Raise 2 ^ 15       , , "This is a user-defined error." 'Overflow.
    err.Raise vbObjectError, , "This is a user-defined error." 'It laughed at me.
ErrorHandler:
    UDE = VBA.CVErr(err.Number)
End Function
```

Comment: Ha, first time seeing `CVErr` used outside of Excel, to mean anything other than a "cell error value". IMO in the vast majority of cases, errors should be *raised*, not *returned*.

Comment: True in other circumstances, but Access VBA functions used in queries can be called thousands, even millions of times in a few seconds. It'd be pretty unwieldy to attempt to handle that with button clicks. But if an error is returned by a function call in a query, Access doesn't miss a beat and just displays `#ERROR` in those cells of the datasheet view, pretty much the same as Excel. I think it may even say `#ERROR 12345` if one were to expand the column width enough to read it, but I don't recall. The last time I saw it I didn't stop to look; I just fixed it & carried on..

Comment: I think of functions for use in queries to be something like a VBA classes; kick the errors out to the caller.

Answer (score 1):

The `vbObjectError` constant is useful to ensure your custom error numbers never colliding with a "built-in" error number, which makes error handling more robust in a way: it ensures error e.g. #91 consistently means "object reference not set", for example.

It implies custom errors are *thrown/raised* and *handled*, though - not *returned*.

Don't get me wrong: *returning* an `Error`-type value *does* have legitimate uses; like when you're writing a user-defined worksheet function and need Excel to distinguish between e.g. "an invalid reference was provided" (`#REF!`), "no match was found for the specified value" (`#N/A`), or "I've no idea what you're talking about" (`#NAME?`); in the Excel type library each of these errors have a corresponding `XlErrXxxxx` global constant defined, with an underlying value in the low 2000's.

It's entirely possible there's a similar use case in Access (I'm not all that familiar with Access), meaning the caller receiving the error is the Access query engine, much like the caller of a UDF in Excel is Excel's calculation engine.

Otherwise (i.e. if the caller is other VBA code), *returning* an error amounts to using the `Error` type for *flow control*, and making things return `Variant` meaning "this function might return a meaningful value of some type, or some error, maybe"... generally makes the code harder to read/follow.

So in use cases where the caller isn't your own VBA code, for error codes you mean to return as `Error`-type values (which is **much** cleaner than returning some magic non-zero `Long` number with the same meaning), you will want to skip the `vbObjectError` part.

Think of `vbObjectError` errors as "internal errors" that your VBA code *handles*, and `Error`/`CVErr` errors as "user-facing errors" that your VBA code *returns*. As come sort of self-inflicted convention =)

If the error you mean to expose is an actual custom VBA error code that you handle elsewhere in your VBA project, you'll want to "map" it to a finite-set of "user-facing" error codes - probably by defining constants, or enums for them:

```
Private Const ERR_CUSTOM_ERROR_1 = vbObjectError + 42

Public Enum UserFacingError
    ErrFooWasNotBarred = &H7E1
    ErrSomething
    ErrSomethingElse
End Enum

'...

Public Function DoSomething(ByVal foo As Long) As Variant
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    '..."happy path"...
    Exit Function
ErrHandler:
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case 5 'Invalid procedure call/argument
            DoSomething = CVErr(ErrFooWasNotBarred)
        Case ERR_CUSTOM_ERROR_1
            DoSomething = CVErr(ErrSomething)
        Case Else
            DoSomething = CVErr(ErrSomethingElse)
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: Blergh. Yea, Access has no equivalent of `Excel.XlErrXxxxx`; they're all Long numbers. Last time I looked (yesterday), there were 2,688 of them: `http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/errors/ErrorNumber_Description2007.html`. And many of them even have replaceable parameter characters in them, such as `|` and `@`. Well...I guess I'll just have to quash my enthusiasm and stick with the basics for query-called functions and return CVErr(1) for everything, lol.